# Windows 7 hangs on using Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-7, crash, adobe-reader

Windows 7 often hangs when I open some pdf file with Adobe Reader.

First of all, Adobe Reader crashes and as soon as it stops, the window hangs and after few seconds, it displays a message quoting "Dumping Physical Memory" in a typical Windows 98 manner and then the system reboots.

This problem persists each time I use Adobe Reader. However, I have installed Foxit Reader to view PDF files. But there are some issues with that also. As sometimes I have editable files, which could be done in Adobe Reader's newest version only.

Suggestions on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: If this problem exists in both `Foxit Reader` and `Adobe Reader` this indicates a hardware problem not a software problem. We need more information on the exact crash in order to help.  Its very unlikely that software alone could be causing this problem.

Comment: reboot in Safe Mode check out the System Event logs for signs of Memory errors, then I would check the Application event logs for 'Application hang' errors related to Adobe.

Comment: This problem exists 9only in adobe reader. when i open any pdf file, just after 5 or 6 six seconds, firstly adobe reader hangs and when i forcefully close reader, the system reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but maybe the problem is the app that created the pdf. Do you have Acrobat Pro, Illustrator, any program that will open the pdf. If you do, and can open it successfully, use save as and then see if Reader can open it. You could also try emailing it to yourself and viewing it in a browser. Just a few steps to determine if the problem is some incompatibility between the pdf and Reader.